# Equivalent circuits in case of equipotential nodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, analog, circuit-design

I have the following basic questions about circuit theory.

1) Consider a generic circuit. Suppose that, because of symmetry or other reasons, we conclude that two nodes A and B of it have the same potential with respect to GND (VA = VB). Are we authorized to put a short circuit between that node and analyze the circuit we get?

2) Suppose that, for instance because of symmetry, we conclude that no current flows on a certain resistor. For instance, no current flows on the central resistor of a Wheatston Bridge when all its 4 resistances are equal:

[image]

Since no current flows on RL, are we authorized to replace it with a short circuit, or with an open circuit, and then solve the resulting circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since no current flows on RL, are we authorized to replace it with a
>   short circuit, or with an open circuit, and then solve the resulting
>   circuit?

Yes you can do this on this particular circuit but be careful about expanding that idea; if you did it on an op-amp circuit (because you assumed that the voltage between Vin- and Vin+ was zero i.e. a virtual earth) you would get into a mess.

It's a similar story when using an op-amp (or BJT) as a voltage follower in (for instance), a Sallen Key filter.

In other words you have to be selective to how far you can generally assume that an open circuit can be a short circuit (or vice versa) if the voltages are equal.